# How add Filter by Tags and by categories to custom post type in Gutenberg block

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, block-editor

I need to add Filter by Tags and by categories to custom post type in Gutenberg block. I have created a CPT called "newsfeed" and it is displayed correctly in the page editor as shown in the following image.

[image: newsfeed]

but does not have the options Filter by Categories and by Filter by Tags like in the post type "Posts".

What can I do to enable these options?

[image: posts]

This is the code I use to create the newsfeeds

```
function add_tags_categories_taxonomy_x5642() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Feed Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Feed Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Feed Tags' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Feed Tags' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Feed Tag' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Feed Tag' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Feed Tag' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Feed Tag' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Feed Tags' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy('feeds_tags', 'newsfeed', $args);
    
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Feed Symbols', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Feed Symbols', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Feed Symbols' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Feed Symbols' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Feed Symbols' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Feed Symbols' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Feed Symbols' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Feed Symbols' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Feed Symbols' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy('feeds_symbols', 'newsfeed', $args);

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category','newsfeed');
}
add_action('init', 'add_tags_categories_taxonomy_x5642');

function add_feed_post_type_x1234($query) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', ['post', 'newsfeed']);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'add_feed_post_type_x1234');
```

Comment: I don't know what block added that "Query Settings" panel, but from what I could tell, your `newsfeed` CPT needs to support the default `category` and `post_tag` *taxonomies*.

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ thanks for your support. how can I make my CPT have this support?

Comment: Basically, just add `'taxonomies' => [ 'category', 'post_tag' ]` to your CPT arguments when you register the CPT. More details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#taxonomies-2).

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you, I wil test.